# CheckedChanged event doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, radio-button, updatepanel

I have make a structure like this:

> - Topic 1
>
>   - Topic A
>
>     - Topic α
>     - Topic β
>   - Topic B
>
>     - Topic γ
>     - Topic δ
> - Topic 2
>
>   - Topic C
>
>     - Topic ε
>     - Topic ζ
>   - Topic D
>
>     - Topic η
>     - Topic θ

First comes topics 1 and 2 on screen. By checking one of them Topic A and B or C and D comes on screen. Finally coms α until θ on screen dependent on the chosen letters. I do this with the following code:

ASP.NET

```
<asp:ScriptManager EnablePartialRendering="true" runat="server" />

<div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnlTopics" UpdateMode="Always" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>

            <asp:Panel ID="pnlNumbers" CssClass="topics" runat="server" />
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlLetters" CssClass="topics" runat="server" />
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlRoman" CssClass="topics" runat="server" />

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

</div>
```

C#

```
private List<TopicNumbers> _allTopics;
private TopicNumber _topicNumber;

protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await LoadTopics();
}

private async Task LoadTopics()
{
    _allTopics = await GetAllTopics(); //this gets all topics from database

    foreach (TopicNumber number in _allTopics)
    {
        MakeRadioButton<TopicNumber>(number, pnlNumbers, new EventHandler(rbtNumber_CheckedChanged));
    }
}

private void rbtNumber_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton rbt = (RadioButton)sender; // 1 ● --> stop always

    pnlLetters.Controls.Clear();
    pnlRomain.Controls.Clear();

    if (rbt.Checked)
    {
        _topicNumber = (from number in _allTopics
                        where number.Naam == rbt.Text
                        select number).First<TopicNumber>();

        foreach (TopicLetter letter in _topicNumber.Letters) //Letters contains a list with all the letters for that number
        {
            MakeRadioButton<TopicLetter>(letter, pnlLetters, new EventHandler(rbtLetter_CheckedChanged));
        }
    }
}

public void rbtLetter_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton rbt = (RadioButton)sender; // 2 ● --> don't stop

    pnlRoman.Controls.Clear();

    if (rbt.Checked)
    {
       TopicLetters letter = (from letter in _topicNumber.Letters
                              where letter.Naam == rbt.Text
                              select letter).First<TopicLetters>();

       foreach (TopicRomain romain in letter.Romans) //contains a list with all roman letters for that western letter
       {
            RadioButton rbtRoman = new RadioButton() {
                Text = roman.ToString(),
                GroupName = "roman",
                AutoPostBack = true
            };

            pnlRoman.Controls.Add(rbtRoman);

            pnlRoman.Controls.Add(new Literal() {
                Text = "<br/>"
            });
        }
    }
}

private void MakeRadioButton<T>(T type, Panel pnl, EventHandler evt)
{
    RadioButton rbt = new RadioButton() {
        Text = type.ToString(),
        GroupName = pnl.ID,
        ID = type.ToString(),
        AutoPostBack = true,
        CssClass = "topic"
    };

    rbt.CheckedChanged += evt;

    //\\
    updPnlCategorieen.Triggers.Add(new AsyncPostBackTrigger() {
        ControlID = rbt.ID,
        EventName = "CheckedChanged"
    });

    pnl.Controls.Add(rbt);

    pnl.Controls.Add(new Literal() {
        Text = "<br/>"
    });
}
```

---

Now my problem is when I will show the roman letters. My code looks to be good (think I), but `rbtLetter_CheckedChanged` never runs. I've place two breakpoints (see ● in code), but the compiler always stops on the first one and never by the second one.

Some images for explain it better:

1. First state = beginning state: *(only numbers are show)* **ok**

   [image]

   I check one of the numbers.
2. Second state: *(only numbers and letters are show)* **ok**

   [image]

   I check one of the letters.
3. Third state: *(numbers, letters and roman must be show)* **error**

   [image]

---

**Edit: august 15, 2015**

I've also try to add a trigger on the `UpdatePanel` everytime a `Checkbox` is created.

This is my code that I used for it *(stands `//\\` on code above)*.

```
updTopics.Triggers.Add(new AsyncPostBackTrigger()
{
    ControlID = rbtNumber.ID, // or rbtLetter
    EventName = "CheckedChanged"
});
```

But it is always the same problem that the roman and the letters are deleted.

---

**Edit: august 27, 2015**

Anyone *(on another community)* said me that there is a [page life cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx). Now I know why this code is not working. But I don't know how to solve this.

I know this question is too broad, but can anyone help me or give me a hint for my problem? I will test it if your idea works. I'm really new with ASP.net.
Thanks for all help and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Does the compiler stop on `rbtNumber.CheckedChanged += rbtNumber_CheckedChanged;`?

Comment: @DangerZone: yes, he stop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the way you have develop it, goes it never work. `UpdatePanel`s can not be used for that. An alternative you can use are user controls. and into that control can `UpdatePanel`s work.